Doubts regarding the statement "Ampere's circuital law does not depend on Biot-Savart Law"
Here Ampere's circuital law is specifically referring to: $\oint{\vec{B} \cdot \vec{dl}}=u_o\cdot I $ , I do not think it's also considering the displacement current, according to the statement.
Since Maxwell's equations have ampere's law, and not biot savart's law, I was thinking Ampere's law is fundamental.
The question was asked in an exam and I would like to challenge the answer key, hence my delibaration to ask the question, I want to find some sources to support my challenge, any help would be nice.

What is the difference between Biot-Savart law and Ampere's law? is probably a duplicate but it is for others to judge.

Both the Ampere law and the Biot-Savart law are approximate. The Biot-Savart law is valid even when Ampere's law isn't - in case electric field changes in time, but can be expressed as gradient of some potential.
